# Select * from table where column1 LIKE column2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Fetching only those rows, where value in column1 contains or is like value in column2 of the same table and same row.

E.g, if table looks something like this:

[image]

But I only want to fetch rows where value of column1 matches a part of column2, like this:

[image]
I.e. either col1 like col2 or col2 contains col1, that returns.

For the same I have generated a column with like pattern and used the same pattern in where condition as follows:

```
SELECT '''%''' + cast(t.col1 AS varchar(200))+ '''%''' as MatchThis,
FROM [practice].[tables].[Temp1] t
WHERE t.col2 LIKE '''%''' + cast(t.col1 AS varchar(200))+ '''%'''
```

This ain't helping, maybe because `LIKE` always takes a hard coded QUOTED value and compares it with all the resultant rows of the query.

I have tried with `CONTAINS` as well, but that doesn't work either.

Stuck in this now, is there any other way out.

Comment: 'Peps**i**' is not part of 'Peps**o**dent' however. And '**L**ife' isn't part of 'Met**l**ife' either if you consider upper/lower case.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah apologies, mistyped that, It'd be %peps%, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.*
from [practice].[tables].[Temp1] t
where t.col2 like '%' + col1 + '%';
```

Your query seems overcomplicated relative to the question.  The question is about comparing two columns, so that should suggest some sort of condition in the `WHERE` clause.